# Is it possible to enforce a naming standard for an BIM360 Docs folder through the data-management API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I've been trying to enforce a predefined naming-standard on an Autodesk BIM360 Docs folder.

There exists an API endpoint to get the naming-standard that is enforced for a BIM360 Docs folder by calling

GET `projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id`

and also

GET `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/docs/v1/projects/:projectId/naming-standards/:id`

to get the details of the defined naming standard.

But there seems to be no public API to enforce a naming standard on a newly created folder. Which is strange since one can set a naming standard via the UI.

I've checked what happens when a user enforces a naming standard via the UI. The UI calls this API

POST `/dm/v3/projects/<ProjectId>/folders/naming-standards:batch-enforce`

with this data

`[{"folderUrn":"<folderId>", "namingStandardId":"<namingStandardId>", "includeSubfolders":false,"operation":"add"}]`

I tried calling the same API programmatically and got an error that my registered forge app has no access to the specified api product, although the data-management api is enabled for this app.

Am a little helpless of how to continue. Perhaps someone can give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the naming standard API is READ-ONLY currently. The Write API is still on the way to come. Please stay tuned with us.

Note. The API you found is for Docs Service itself only.